# Cross-filtering across different pages

Tags: dropdown, crossfilter

I'm trying to cross-filter a Drop-down on Page 1 to a series of charts/tables on multiple pages.  I can apply to Page 1 but not other pages.  Is this possible?

I see the option to apply to charts/tables on Page 1 where the drop-down also exists but can't determine how to apply to charts/tables on Page 2, 3, etc.

Appreciate any help you all can provide!  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Specifically, what technologies are you asking about? Many tools have a "cross filter" of some sort. The [crossfilter] tag refers to a specific JavaScript implementation, but my guess is that you are using PowerBI or something else.